# How to calculate intensity mean square difference using Opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

There is a way to calculate the difference between two images called "intensity mean square difference" (MSD). I found it in [this](http://www.cse.iitk.ac.in/users/vision/dipen/references/Replay%20detection%20in%20broadcastign%20sports%20video.pdf) research paper. I'm searching for a way to implement that using opencv and C++. Any reference regarding this is highly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe background substraction or optical flow is what you need.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that it's the same as `CV_TM_SQDIFF` mode of [`matchTemplate`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/object_detection.html?highlight=matchtemplate#matchtemplate) but which is normed by number of pixels. It can be calculated for images A and B as follows:

[image: MSD formula]

where n - number of pixels on image

I don't suggest you using `matchTemplate` function to calculate this. It's more effective to use [`cv::norm`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#norm) as follows:

```
double MSD = cv::norm(A, B);
MSD = MSD * MSD / A.total();
```